# General tips for several long flights within a short period?

Tags: travel

I'm going to be on three flights within a 33 hour period, adding up to 25 hours of flying with about four hours between each flight. What tips do you have for getting through such long hauls with minimal discomfort?

Comment: What aspect are you looking for a hack for? E.g. boredom, sleep, waking up at the right time, safety, security, etc.

Comment: @Lawrence It's a case of unknown unknowns, since I've never experienced extremely long hauls without a proper break. Clarified that it's mostly about comfort though.

Comment: Ah, have a look at [travel.se].

Answer (score 4):

The only one  I can think of is to take a aspirin before the flight. It has anti-clotting properties that help prevent deep vein thrombosis in the legs. A blood clot can form when in the seated position for extended periods of time. You can check this out with your physician to see it he or she concurs and to recommend a safe dose.

Answer (score 2):

- Earbuds (and possibly a spare)
- Book
- Journal and pen for journaling or taking notes if something comes to you during the trip that you want to write down
- Snacks, if you think the plane food won't be very good or not enough
- Puzzle book
- Download a bunch of podcasts to your phone or tablet and listen to them
- At least 2 cell phone chargers (the lipstick size kind)
- Pillow and eye mask, if you think you might fall asleep
- Blanket, if you think you might get cold
- Small hand sanitizer
- Face and/or hand wipes, travel-size